# Writing one CSV file for each text file containg driving license information

Tags: python, csv, text-files

[J RYBEWYS

1 Mesters:

Lambertus #

» 05.01.1979 Eindhoven
40.31.01.2017 4» 31.01.2027
4< Gemeente Waaire

5740344641

AM-BE
, a T

D1NLD1574034464194NB44MK362D54][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL4jg.png)

I have more than thousands of text files containing the information shown in the example image and I want to write one CSV file for each text file. The text files contain driving license information. I want to put each line into a separate column.

I am using this piece of code:

```
 #list the files
 filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 
 #read them into pandas
  df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, header = None, encoding='latin1') for file in filelist]
  df_list.to_csv('D:/Athora/CSV/text.csv', index = None, encoding='latin1')
```

I am getting following error with this code:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 
      4 #read them into pandas
----> 5 df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, header = None, encoding='latin1') for file in filelist]
      6 df_list.to_csv('D:/Athora/CSV/text.csv', index = None, encoding='latin1')

Input In [8], in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 
      4 #read them into pandas
----> 5 df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, header = None, encoding='latin1') for file in filelist]
      6 df_list.to_csv('D:/Athora/CSV/text.csv', index = None, encoding='latin1')

File D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:678, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    663 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    664     dialect,
    665     delimiter,
   (...)
    674     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    675 )
    676 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 678 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:575, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    572 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    574 # Create the parser.
--> 575 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    577 if chunksize or iterator:
    578     return parser

File D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:932, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    929     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    931 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 932 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1216, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1212     mode = "rb"
   1213 # error: No overload variant of "get_handle" matches argument types
   1214 # "Union[str, PathLike[str], ReadCsvBuffer[bytes], ReadCsvBuffer[str]]"
   1215 # , "str", "bool", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any", "Any"
-> 1216 self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1217     f,
   1218     mode,
   1219     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
   1220     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
   1221     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
   1222     is_text=is_text,
   1223     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
   1224     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
   1225 )
   1226 assert self.handles is not None
   1227 f = self.handles.handle

File D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:786, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    781 elif isinstance(handle, str):
    782     # Check whether the filename is to be opened in binary mode.
    783     # Binary mode does not support 'encoding' and 'newline'.
    784     if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    785         # Encoding
--> 786         handle = open(
    787             handle,
    788             ioargs.mode,
    789             encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    790             errors=errors,
    791             newline="",
    792         )
    793     else:
    794         # Binary mode
    795         handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DLcasper.jpg.txt'
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Also, if you have any alternate solution, please let me know.

Comment: So I am clear, you have a directory of text files and you want to write each file in the directory into a CSV? Is it one CSV or a CSV for each corresponding text file? The last line of your error is telling you that 'DLcasper.jpg.txt' is not found.

Comment: CSV files _are_ text files; it's not clear what "corresponding" means here.

Comment: No they're not. They contain plain text but they are comma separated tabular data files. Meaning for each .txt file, do they want a corresponding .csv file.

Comment: So, I want to write one CSV file for each text file. The text file doesn't contain the CSV format. It contains information extracted from a driving license.

Answer (score 1):

Python can't find the files (hence the FileNotFoundError), because

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, header = None, encoding='latin1') for file in filelist]
```

gives a list of filenames (without the actual path to the file). If you add the path, it should read the files without a problem.

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(f'{targetdir}/{file}', header = None, encoding='latin1') for file in filelist]
```

While that solves the problem of loading the files, the next line of your code will also produce an error. You are trying to use an attribute (.to_csv) for a list (and also save all your text files to the same .csv file - so you are overwriting the same file every time).
Instead, try looping through the list and save each file separately.

```
for idx, item in enumerate(df_list):
    item.to_csv(f'test{idx}.csv', index=None, encoding='latin1')
```

The above code iterates through the list of loaded txt files and exports them to a separate .csv file using the 'loop count' (idx) to give the files a unique filename.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your solution. I applied your suggestion but it's throwing an error that there is no column to parse. The text file I am trying to write into CSV contains driving license information. It doesn't have a column format but I replaced the '\n' with ',' in the text file. So, I can use ',' as a delimiter when parsing. Also, when I am doing it just for one file the parsing works perfectly fine but it's not working for multiple files.